# Using a Sharepoint 2013 developed add-in on sharepoint on-premise

Tags: sharepoint-addin, napa

I am very new to Sharepoint development. I have developed a very simple add-in for Sharepoint 2013 using the Napa IDE from within Sharepoint and I was wondering if this app is supported by older, on-premise versions on Sharepoint (that most of my potential clients are using).

It's a very simple add-in that basically just renders some content using Javascript into the iFrame.

Comment: What do you mean by "older on-premise versions"? Do you want to use this add-in in on-premise?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Apologies, my lack of understand of how Sharepoint works is apparently showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a NAPA App on-premises, *but* (as always in SP, there's a *but* somewhere in the phrase):

- Your on-premises environment must be configured for Apps (Application services provisioned, catalog site created, wilcard DNS name registered, maybe IE zone settings set-up, ...). See articles like https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx or http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/01/31/configuring-sharepoint-on-premise-deployments-for-apps.aspx. [You see the former? That's exactly why I hate apps: all these explanations and schemas to explain how to just *setup* an environment!]
- Other type of apps (aka add-ins) may not be supported (like oAuth provider-hosted apps)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the target environment is still SharePoint 2013, you should be able to install whatever app you built into the catalogue -- if you used some new feature that is only available in modern releases of SharePoint online you may have a compatability issue, but that would vary based on the specific features you used in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NAPA developed Add-Ins work in all **SP2013** environments, On-Prem and Online.

SP2010 (and earlier) do not have any add-in capabilities.

Note that using IFRAME technology your end users (administrators) might have blocked external access to your (external) URLs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've setup the add-in environment in your on premise server and your on premise server is running SP 2013, you should be able to use your NAPA developed add-in on your on premise environment as well.